# Ubuntu does not boot, but windows does

Tags: boot, bios

On my old computer I would like to install ubuntu 12.10. Now the strange thing is it does not boot the dvd disc from ubuntu. The windows disc however boots normally. If I disable the harddisk in the bios settings it does boot, but now I don't see a harddisk during the installation.

Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In the BIOS don't disable the hard disk completely just look for boot order, to make it attempt to boot from the CD before the hard disk.

Comment: Yes I did that and the windows cd boots, but it does not boot for the ubuntu cd.

Comment: @Remco Try a liveUSB instead